# Bash: Export functions for use in xargs

Tags: bash, function, export, subshell

When my bash scripts start getting complex, I usually break them up into functions. This applies especially to complex pipes, as a sequence of complicated pipe commands (e.g. containing while-loops) can quickly become hard to read. Even more so when parallelization is wanted, where xargs is very helpful.

I know that I can export functions to a subshell with `export -f`, thus in a simple case I can do

```
export -f myfunction 
some-command | xargs -Iline bash -c "myfunction 'line'"
```

but if the `myfunction` depends on other functions this becomes hard to maintain -- every time the function changes such that the functions needed by the subshell for executing `myfunction` change, the export statement would have to be changed -- that seems pretty error prone.

Is there some general way to export functions for use by subshells? I was thinking about something along the lines of an "export all defined functions" command, which would then allow a code structure like

```
main() { ... }
func1 () { ... }
func2 () { ... }
<export all functions>
main "$@"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question asks only about exporting functions. This is easy in bash, see below.

Your question title/subject implies using functions in xargs, as though they were a script;
I don't know that xargs can "call" a bash function directly, but you can of course wrap
your use of the exported function(s) in a script called by `xargs`, see below.

First, a function to list functions. User functions by default and -v to list all functions:

```
lsfns () {
   case "$1" in
      -v | v*)
         # verbose:
         set | grep '()' --color=always
         ;;
      *)
         declare -F | cut -d" " -f3 | egrep -v "^_"
         ;;
   esac
}
```

Next a function to export all user functions:

```
exportfns () { export -f $(lsfns); }
```

or just put `export -f $(lsfns)` in your `.bashrc`.

Example script doit.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
lsfns "$@" # make use of function exported by parent shell :)
```

Example command line (after `chmod a+rx doit.sh`):

```
echo -v | xargs doit.sh
```

Compare with

```
echo "" | xargs doit.sh
```

---

EDIT 1: responding further to kdb's comment/answer below ("running into situations where exporting functions does not work at all"):

Export of shell functions is not Posix compatible - i.e. it only works with Bash and presumably other shells such as Zsh, Ksh etc.

That is, in Dash, and "standard" Posix shells not providing "export -f", we cannot export functions, AND if we export a function say in Bash, then run a script which starts with the sh-bang e.g. "#!/bin/dash", that script will NOT be able to use the "exported" functions from the parent shell, since functions exported to the "process environment" by Bash, are not recognised by Dash.

---

EDIT 2: responding further to OP comment "but if the `myfunction` depends on other functions this becomes hard to maintain":

This is probably a situation where one could make good use of the shell `source` command (alias "."), e.g.:

```
. ~/etc/my-functions.sh; myMain ...
```

And similarly, if you "live" in functions rather than script files, e.g. by calling `myMain` when you need to, then the first line of this function can be to source your function library;

since this would be excess overhead in the "running a script regularly" case, `myMain` becomes the command-line stub function, which (re)loads your function library, and calls the `actuallyDoit` function (which would also be called from inside your script, if you have a script file).

Enjoy
Zenaan

Comment: Actually my question includes an example of using xargs, so I don't see what you mean by the second paragraph. I appreciate the rest of the answer though (`exportfns` will help).

Comment: I was clarifying for future readers, in case someone tries to "call" a function directly using xargs, treating that function as though it were a script, for example `find dir/ | xargs aBashFn` which won't work - you must wrap the function in a script, or as in your first example, spawn a bash subshell - but fork bash is a pretty heavy way to call a function, unless you only need it once. I hope that explains why I wrote that...

Comment: "Export of shell functions is not Posix compatible - i.e. it only works with Bash" THANK YOU. I had `xargs sh -c` and when I replaced it with `xargs bash -c` then all of my `export -f` functions worked!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work to print all the function names. It *feels* fragile, so test it out

```
declare -f | grep -oP '^\S+(?=\s*\(\))'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export -f $(compgen -A function)
```

Comment: While I first thought this was a great answer for its simplicity, I sadly found that it breaks xargs. I get "xargs: environment is too large for exec". This might be cygwin-specific though as Windows seems to limit the length of environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since receiving the answer, I found many cases where a different technique proofed preferable: Making the script invoke itself. A simple example would be

```
# Print hash and disk usage for each argument
if [[ $1 == run ]]; then
  shift 1
  printf "%s\0" "$@" | xargs -0 -n 1 -P "$NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS" -- "$0" printpar
elif [[ $1 == printpar ]]; then
  echo ":: $(cat "$2" | sha1sum) $(du -sh "$2")"
else
  echo "Invalid first parameter '$1'"
  exit 1
fi
```

In real-world examples I'd either make assumptions about the arguments (e.g. using `__SUCH__` a shape for self-call keywords) or hide recursive invocations behind an undocumented `--command-line-switch`.

Exporting functions is generally more elegant, but for large numbers of function it can get prohibitively slow and I remember running into issues, where it failed entirely.